# The ETA to close (down) the task is the first of January - which version is grammatically sound?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, phrasal-verbs

Which of the following sentences is grammatically sound?

1. The ETA to close the task is the first of January
2. The ETA to close down the task is the first of January.

What difference does it make if I replace *close/close down* with *complete*?

Comment: This depends on the context. Certain work fields have their own jargon, and either "close" or "close down" might be correct.

Answer (score 1):

The first option is the correct one.

> The ETA to close the task is 01Jan.

This is also good. Close can be used interchangeable with complete.

> The ETA to complete the task is 01Jan.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, one will “complete a task”.

“close a task” wouldn’t generally sound right except as shorthand for closing a ticket in some sort of task tracking software after you have *completed* the task.

“close down” has a sense of forcefulness and finality, such as “health authorities closed down a restaurant found to be serving rotten meat.” This is rarely what you want.

Comment: Yes, to 'close down' a task would be to abandon work on it altogether. That is something that would usually be done immediately the decision was taken, not something that would be done by a target date.

Comment: @BoldBen ... unless there is a qualifier, for example: "... if they don't start to improve performance." Been there done that ...

Answer (score 0):

Neither look very good.  The use of "ETA" (expected time of arrival) with "close (down) a task" is at best unnecessary management jargon, and at worse incomprehensible.

There's no need to use "ETA" here.  Nothing is arriving, even in a metaphorical sense. And "complete" is a good clear word. "Complete" is far better than "close down".

> The expected completion date of the task is Jan 1st.

(or more actively)

> I expect to complete the task by Jan 1st.

<sub>Side note — Having a completion date on Jan 1st, when in most of the world everybody will be on holiday might not be the best plan...</sub>

Answer (score 0):

To be pedantic, the literal meaning of "ETA" is "Estimated Time of Arrival" and thus refers to things, not actions. Under this view, grammatical correctness would require it be reworded with a noun, such as "The ETA of the task closure is 1 Jan".

However, "ETA" has achieved a meaning distinct from its literal meaning, so most people wouldn't consider using it with an action to be ungrammatical.

"Target Completion Date is 1 Jan" would avoid both this issue and the one you raise in your question, although it implies a more prescriptive position as opposed to the more descriptive "ETA".

As for whether "close" should be followed by a proposition. "close down" has an air of stopping something. "Close" or "close out" are better for communicating that the issue will be addressed.